# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.factual.driver.Factual

Tags: java, android, factual

I have encountered a problem when using Factual API in my Android app.  I think I've added all the correct jar files.  Take a look here:

[image: jar files]

Here is my logcat:

```
11-30 19:27:03.033: E/AndroidRuntime(4538): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-30 19:27:03.033: E/AndroidRuntime(4538): Process: com.example.foodsaver2, PID: 4538
11-30 19:27:03.033: E/AndroidRuntime(4538): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.factual.driver.Factual
11-30 19:27:03.033: E/AndroidRuntime(4538):     at com.example.foodsaver2.DatabaseFiller.onCreate(DatabaseFiller.java:70)
11-30 19:27:03.033: E/AndroidRuntime(4538):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5243) 
11-30 19:27:03.033: E/AndroidRuntime(4538):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
11-30 19:27:03.033: E/AndroidRuntime(4538):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2140)
11-30 19:27:03.033: E/AndroidRuntime(4538):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
11-30 19:27:03.033: E/AndroidRuntime(4538):     at  android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
11-30 19:27:03.033: E/AndroidRuntime(4538):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
11-30 19:27:03.033: E/AndroidRuntime(4538):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-30 19:27:03.033: E/AndroidRuntime(4538):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-30 19:27:03.033: E/AndroidRuntime(4538):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
11-30 19:27:03.033: E/AndroidRuntime(4538):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-30 19:27:03.033: E/AndroidRuntime(4538):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-30 19:27:03.033: E/AndroidRuntime(4538):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
11-30 19:27:03.033: E/AndroidRuntime(4538):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
11-30 19:27:03.033: E/AndroidRuntime(4538):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

What's wrong here?  What am I doing wrong?  And by the way, here is *part* of my AndroidManifest:

```
application android:label="@string/app_name">
            <uses-library android:name="com.factual.driver.Factual" />

<activity android:name=".DatabaseFiller" android:label="@string/app_name">
```

And from line 70 of DatabaseFiller:

```
/*this is line 69, next line is 70*/ try {
        Factual factual = new Factual("perosnal", "personal");
        factual.fetch("products-cpg-nutrition", 
                new Query().search("028367831679"));
        // row filter
        Query q = new Query();
        factual.fetch("products-cpg-nutrition", 
                q.or(q.field("upc").isEqual("028367831679"),
                        q.field("ean13").isEqual("028367831679")));
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), (CharSequence) q, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {

    }
```

What's wrong here?  I'm been banging my head on the wall for a while now.  I have checked SO and Google, but I can't pin the needle on the solution.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

---

EDIT!
Another message is also showing up in Logcat that I forgot to add:

```
11-30 20:44:09.993: E/dalvikvm(11654): Could not find class 'com.factual.driver.Factual', referenced from method com.example.foodsaver2.DatabaseFiller.onCreate
```

But I have it in my AndroidManifest file.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please do not treat this as an answer, rather as a comment. I do not have privilege to comment yet. Please do not negate it as well.

As of what I comprehend :

The line you mentioned, cannot be the location of error.
Because if it would had encountered any issue in the try block, your code`(try and catch)` is `swallowing the exception stopping it from throwing an exception`.

This is possibly the wrong spot where you are searching for error.

Moreover, if it is not able to recognize `'Factual'` in instance creation it would give a compilation error not a runtime exception.

```
I would say figure out the exact location of the issue.
```

Comment: Good point, but how do I exactly pinpoint the location of the issue.  Forgive me, I am a 13 year old beginner.

Comment: @Rohodude : I am really glad to meet students like you who start programming really early. I was very late to start on with it. 


As far as finding the issue in your code 

'com.example.foodsaver2.DatabaseFiller.onCreate(DatabaseFiller.java:70)'

This says you might have issue in the onCreate() method. Just check up there.

During development, I would suggest you print the stack trace in every catch that you have.

try
{
...
}
catch(Exception e)
{
e.printStackTrace();
}

This would help you reach to the crux of the issue.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at it.  I'll comment when I find something.

Comment: For some reason, the code is still stuck in the try method.  When I added `e.printStackTrace()` to the catch method, nothing showed up in the Logcat.  The only thing that showed up was the cause of the crash of the app.  Help is needed! (and appreciated)